# NullPointerException while setting Resource Bundle in Codenameone

Tags: nullpointerexception, codenameone

I am testing translation in codename one, just used the Chrome Example added code to read "en" local I think, and I am receiving this exception, here is the code, thank you

```
public class Chrome {
private Resources theme;

private Form current;
public void init(Object context) {
    theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");
     
}

public void start() {
    String local = L10NManager.getInstance().getLanguage();
    System.err.println("local: "+local);
    UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(theme.getL10N("l10n", local));
```

Here is Output:

```
    local: en
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.getL10N(Resources.java:834)
    at com.codename1.demo.chrome.Chrome.start(Chrome.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$3$1.run(Executor.java:258)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1331)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1125)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This NPE will happen if there's no localization resource named "l10n" in the resource bundle. You need to add a localization bundle and name it exactly (case sensitive no spaces) "l10n".

Comment: Thank you, the designer gives a long name by default, thank you Shai!!!!

Comment: So you can rename it in the designer to l10n